# Recursive function to determine if a combination of words of len n exist

Tags: python, recursion

I had a class on recursion and some assignments. Here is one I can't solve at all.

We have a list in the following format `['word','blabla','thing']` and a number L as input.

The idea is to try to find if there's a way to combine some words (or take just one) if the number of the characters/combination of words is equal to L.
Note: if we have a combination, then we must count commas (separators) in the total number of characters

For example : `print(recursive_func(['word','blabla','thing'], 12))` should return `True`.

Indeed blabla has a length of 6 and thing a length of 5 and we have a comma so that makes a total of 12.

I have the following code :

```
def recursive_func(words, L):
  if len(words) == 1 or len(words[-1]) == L:
    return len(words[-1]) == L
  last_word = words[-1]
  without_last_word = words[:-1]
  return ??? or ???
```

So I understand the code cause I did a similar one previously but I have no idea on what to put on those "???".

Since it's about recursion, we obviously need to put something like `recursive_func(without_last_word, L)`
My guess is that it's necessary to decrease L by `len(words[-1])` and then try if there's a match.

But I have no idea what is actually the way to do it nor can I code it properly.

Could you give a piece of advice?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to try to choose a word, and see if a solution exists with the remaining words. If not, then we can eliminate that word.

```
def recursive_func(words, L):
    # A direct fit?
    if any(len(w) == L for w in words):
        return True

    # We try the ith word w, and see if a combo solution exists
    # including that word, otherwise we eliminate it.
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        remaining_candidates = words[i+1:]
        if recursive_func(remaining_candidates, L - len(w) - 1):
            return True
    
    return False
```

Comment: While your direct fit check works, a simpler base case would be to check if `L == 0`

Comment: @Barmar You're forgetting about the comma.

Comment: Oh right, there's no comma when a single word matches.

Comment: There is no need to add for loops (especially not 2 in in each recursion). This can be done by recursion itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you need combination of any words, like you can combine `'word'` and `'thing'` passing `'blabla'` from your example, you can write something like that:

```
def recursive_func(words, L, used, cnt):
    if (cnt == L):
        return True
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if (not used[i]):
            used[i] = True
            if (recursive_func(words, L, used, len(words[i]) if cnt == 0 else cnt + len(words[i]) + 1)):
                return True
            used[i] = False
    return False
recursive_func(words, L, [False] * len(words), 0)
```

where `used` is an array which knows used words in current combination, `cnt` is length of current combination.

Comment: Changing the signature to add information is not needed, see my answer. Also, looping through all words is not needed if you build two trees recursively instead of only one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def recursive_func(words, L):

    if sum(map(len, words)) + len(words) - 1 == L:
        return True
    if len(words) == 1:
        return False

    for w in list(words):
        words.remove(w)
        if recursive_func(words, L):
            return True
        words.append(w)
    return False
```

First, you check if the whole list satisfies the condition, if not, you try with a *sublist*.

You could use `itertools` or `set` optionally.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it. We are building 2 trees (with and without the first word) in each recursion. Keep in mind that the words in the combination might not be next to each other.

```
s =["hi","hallo","du"]

def rec(words:list, L:int):
    if not words:
        return False
    elif len(words[0]) == L:
        return True
        elif len(words[0]) > L:
        return False #early stopping
    return rec(words[1:], L-len(words[0])-1) or rec(words[1:],L) #all combinations with and without this word

print(rec(s, 4))
```